# bash: case statement shows no difference between 1 and 11?

Tags: bash, switch-statement

I am trying to convert a certain number from a record in a plain semi-colon separated textfile with

```
 group=$( echo $line | cut -d';' -f6 )
```

The possible values for this column (6) are within the range 1-20.
E.g. if number "11" was found, I have to convert it to "5a"

```
         case ${group} in

         [1]*)
                group='1a';
                echo $group >> "$file"
         esac
         ;;
         [11]*)
                group='5a';
                echo $group >> "$file"
          esac
           ;;
```

However, everytime I execute the script all values from 10-19 are defaulting to the [1] switch.
I tried to quote the switches like ["11"] or ['11'], without success.
How to switch the 10-19 values correctly?

Comment: Isn't your code syntactically incorrect? Why do you have two 'esac'? The first one shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 4):

`[11]` is the same as `[1]` since it's a character class/range from 1 to 1.

You really don't need the wildcards if your values are numbers: just do the cases like this:

```
     1)
            group='1a';
            echo $group >> "$file"
     esac
     ;;
     11)
            group='5a';
            echo $group >> "$file"
      esac
       ;;
```

(and so on: default case is `*)` BTW)

if the numbers were followed by letters you could do like this:

```
     1[a-z])
            group='1a';
            echo $group >> "$file"
     esac
     ;;
     11[a-z])
            group='5a';
            echo $group >> "$file"
      esac
       ;;
```

Note: If you want to match `11` or `1` followed by anything you can do this:

```
     11*)
            group='5a';
            echo $group >> "$file"
      esac
       ;;

     1*)
            group='1a';
            echo $group >> "$file"
     esac
     ;;
```

(the 2nd case will match all numbers starting by 1 but not starting by 11. Note that I have reversed the cases, most accurate match first).

Make your pick :)

Comment: Fabre: Reversing the switch-statement as you suggested, worked very well for me

Comment: That cool! Since I did not know the form of your tokens, I just posted an exhaustive solution.